# A Function to Find Exact Trigonometric Values?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I was messing around with the nth roots of complex numbers, trying to calculate each positive integer root. By the time I got to n=4, I realised this was not the most effective way to be going around this. Obviously,

> $(i)^{1/n} = \cos(\pi/2n) + i \sin(\pi/2n)$

And then I realised that $\cos(\pi/8)$ was not a value my calculator could give me in an irrational form. So, after some juggling with double angle formulae, we have this:

> $(i)^{1/n} = 1/4 \sqrt{(\cos(\pi/n)+1)} + i/4\sqrt{(1-\cos(\pi/n)}$

But, when approaching larger values of n, this becomes more and more tedious to calculate. I was wondering whether anyone knew of a function that I could derive or use to find these exact values more easily? Or is it just something you have to do by hand?

(Also, any help formatting these questions would be appreciated- first time)

Comment: Your calculator can't give $\cos(\pi/4) =1/\sqrt{2}$ in irrational form?

Comment: Any numeric results you will get from the sine and cosine functions also will be approximations of their true irrational values. Unless it's a symbolic calculator like Wolfram Alpha, your calculator probably doesn't even give the number $1/3$ in an exact form. Why are you concerned about how accurately it represents $\pi/(2n)$?

Comment: 1. A typo- my calculator can't give cos(/8) in irrational form

Comment: 2. To answer honestly, I'm not quite sure. I like the idea of trig values being expressed in their exact form as opposed to decimal approximations, it's just something that excites me.

Comment: I see, you wrote "pi/8 ... in an irrational form" but you meant "cos(pi/8) ... in an irrational form". And "irrational form" is a specific symbolic format in your mind; $\cos(\pi/8)$ is not an "irrational form" but $1/\sqrt2$ is. Still, this is puzzling because a decent symbolic calculator ought to be able to do $\cos(\pi/8)$, for example https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cos%28pi%2F8%29 (see "alternate forms").

Comment: $\cos  (\pi /8)$ is a root of the polynomial $1-8 x^2+8 x^4$. you can factor the polynomial, since it is a quadratic in $x^2$

Comment: Every complex root of unity can be expressed in terms of radicals. But it seems the algorithms for finding these in general can be complicated.

Comment: I'm not sure about $\cos(\pi/11)$ to be expressed in radicals